# Why does not std::nothrow work as expected in gcc(4.9)?

Tags: c++, g++

I've seen lots of people in my team checking null pointers like this:

```
    SomeClass *pSc = new SomeClass;
    if ( NULL == pSc )
    {
        // cope with error
    }
```

I known this will not work, because new operator in c++ throws a std::bad_alloc exception instead of returning NULL. I also know that std::nothrow can make what they expected really happen. So I wrote an example like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <limits>
    #include <new>
    using namespace std;

    void myNewHandler()
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to allocate memory!" << std::endl;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        //std::new_handler oldHandler = std::set_new_handler(myNewHandler);

        int *pLotsMem = new(std::nothrow) int[std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()];
        if ( nullptr == pLotsMem )
        {
            std::cerr << "Allocation failed" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            delete[] pLotsMem;
            pLotsMem = nullptr;
        }

        //std::set_new_handler(oldHandler);

        return 0;
    }
```

Yes, I wanted to demonstrate usage of std::set_new_handler as well. To my surprise, even this did not work. new operator still threw an exception(std::bad_array_new_length, a derived class of std::bad_alloc) and then terminated the program.

Any idea why this failed to work? **How should one check pointers returned by new operator in gcc**?

Comment: It works as expected in clang

Comment: Yes! It also works in vc++ compiler.  But I don't know why it fails to work in gcc.

Comment: With `GCC 6.1.0` it won't compile unless you reduce the size to a legal amount. Then it works as expected.

Comment: @Galik How can I find out what the legal limit is? Do you know how big it is in gcc 4.9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe or not, this is standard compliant behavior:

> 5.3.4/7
>
> The expression in a noptr-new-declarator is erroneous if:
>   *[...]* — its value is such that the **size of the allocated object would exceed the implementation-defined limit** (annex B); or
>   *[...]*
>
> If the expression, after converting to std::size_t, is a core constant
>   expression and the expression is erroneous, the program is ill-formed.
>   Otherwise, a **new-expression with an erroneous expression does not
>   call an allocation function and terminates by throwing an exception of
>   a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type
>   std::bad_array_new_length** (18.6.2.2). When the value of the
>   expression is zero, the allocation function is called to allocate an
>   array with no elements.

In short, non-throwing allocator function is not even called, exception is thrown by *new-expression* itself.

I assume that you are not using modern C++ version, because in those `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()` marked as `constexpr` and is a *core constant expression*, which yields compile-time error.

Clang, *probably* has *implementation-defined limit* set higher than max value of long lond, bypassing this quirk of C++.

Comment: Thank you! I changed nullptr back to NULL and compiled the code without "-std=c++11" option. This time it did work as expected. The most modern c++ is so different, there is a lot to learn for me.